# I cannot select a date on a date picker using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium

First ever Stack Overflow question.

I am trying to write a Selenium C# script to get a quote on this page:
https://www.comparethemarket.com/travel-insurance/single-trip/ (click the Start a Quote button and you'll land on the page).  Select single trip and there are start date options - today, tomorrow and other.  I want to select any date from the "other" menu but nothing seems to work.

I can easily find the CSS selectors but actually doing something with them seems impossible. I have tried SendKeys and Builder, and also tried using Javascript to update the values that appear after a real selection (the JS works in that it updates the page but when moving to the next page, the values are the default rather than the updated).  Nothing works.  Can anyone provide a solution to this, please?

I have tried:

```
element = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#CoverStartDate div div > label:nth-of-type(3) div span span > span:nth-of-type(1)').innerText='" + startDateMonth + "';");

element = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#CoverStartDate div div > label:nth-of-type(3) div span span > span:nth-of-type(2)').innerText='" + startDateDay + "';");
```

The JS works but does not solve the issue - when I move to the next page, the date is the default

I've also tried this:

```
 IWebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
 Actions action = new Actions(d);
 action.(Various actions like click, double click, perform);
```

I have also used SendKeys:

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

to highlight the element and then Click().  I've even tried .Submit() but, as it is not a form, it didn't work.

Just to be clear - when I used SendKeys.Tab, I can get to the element that I require.  I just cannot click or otherwise select it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Show us what you have and what's not working so we can help you get it figured out.

Comment: Hi Codexer.  I have updated my question to show what I have tried.  Thanks.

Comment: @Roybut when you select the date, it stores the value in a hidden input element e.g. textbox. You should try to find it and set it directly instead of selecting from the calendar. It will be posted when the form is submitted.

Comment: Hi Aman.  I have tried sending the values straight to the selectors in the code snippets above (SendKeys) and by using JS above.  None of those work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked this out myself so will post this in case anyone else has a similar problem.  I used a collection to get all of the buttons, filtered them into another collection based on an attribute value, and then was able to click the required date.